# How do I get mongo to input my json file without error?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following json data I am trying to import into mongodb.

```
{    
"subjectId": "63cd96779e66d518f3af574c",
"name":"Earth and Space Science",  
"subtopics": [
  {
    "name": "Rocks, Soil and Minerals",
    "questions": [
      {
        "question": "What type of rock is formed when magma cools and hardens?",
        "multipleChoice":["Sedimentary", "Metamorphic", "Igneous",  "All of the above"],
        "answer": "Igneous"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

I am getting the error: Operation passed in cannot be an array.

Do you know why?

Comment: Would you show the full error message and the code/command/operation that produces it?

Comment: I am inputting the file through Mongo's input file option. There is no code involved. And the error shown in my question is the entire error displayed by mongo.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB Compass? ... MongoDB Atlas web interface?  In both, I am able to insert your document by just copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the Problem is the formatted json structure with you tabs and spaces, it has to be unformatted in a Oneliner.

Try this:

```
{"subjectId":"63cd96779e66d518f3af574c","name":"Earth and Space Science","subtopics":[{"name":"Rocks, Soil and Minerals","questions":[{"question":"What type of rock is formed when magma cools and hardens?","multipleChoice":["Sedimentary","Metamorphic","Igneous","All of the above"],"answer":"Igneous"}]}]}
```

Refer to [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/import-a-embedded-json-document-with-compass-error-operation-passed-in-cannot-be-an-array/154021/3).

Comment: Inputted the data as a single line as shown in the example you provided. Didn't work. I am sure I have inputted data into mongo in json structured format before so that can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Compass has an unusual [JSON file import format requirement](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/import-export/#format-your-data) in that each document must be delimited by a newline.

> When importing data from a JSON file, you can format your data as:
>
> - Newline-delimited documents, or
> - Comma-separated documents in an array

After formatting your JSON document file as required, MongoDB Compass imports your file normally.  Hopefully Compass's file import parser will become *"smarter"*.